# python subprocess run shell with gawk regular expression don't work

Tags: python, subprocess, gawk

The bash cmd is :

```
 ps aux |grep tomcat  |grep -Ev grep |grep -o 'Dcatalina.base=.*tomcat' |gawk -F'[ =]+' '{print $2}'"
```

this works well on bash and the output is:

```
/opt/Backuplog/tomcat-6.0.44
```

However, I want to use this cmd in python,so I use the subprocess

```
out=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output,outerr = out.communicate()
```

but the output is `''`, I want to know how to deal with it

Comment: why is there a `"` at the end of the command? (it is invalid syntax). Have you checked *both* `output` *and* `outerr`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `bash` to run it, your command should be:

```
cmd = '''bash -i -c "ps aux |grep tomcat  |grep -Ev grep |grep -o 'Dcatalina.base=.*tomcat' |gawk -F'[ =]+' '{print $2}'"'''
```

Or you can use `subprocess.check_output`:

```
cmd = "ps aux |grep tomcat  |grep -Ev grep |grep -o 'Dcatalina.base=.*tomcat' |gawk -F'[ =]+' '{print $2}'"

subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-i', '-c', cmd])
```

Comment: Use "bash -i -c" dones't work, the output is also ''

Comment: @page Can you tell me if it works for `cmd = "ps -eo comm,pid | grep systemd"`?